# separate while and foreach and have a common array

Tags: php, mysql, sql, foreach

I would like to have a array in the form:

```
[1] => Name1

[2] => Name2

[1] is my $key1

[2] is my $key2
```

But I've got

```
[1] => Name1Name2
[2] => Name1Name2
```

Because of my while and my foreach

I do not know how to do it

I have a little framework but you should understand

```
$uId = gs_post('id');

$array = array();

$Id = '';

foreach ($uId as $key => $value) {
  $Id .= $key.',';
}

$Id = substr($Id ,0,-1);

$sql =
  " SELECT ".
  " D.U_ID, CONCAT(U_NAME,' ',U_SURNAME) AS NAME".
  " FROM TABLE1 AS D".
  " JOIN TABLE2 AS A".
  " ON D.U_ID = A.U_ID".
  " WHERE D.U_ID IN (".$Id.")".
  " GROUP BY U_ID";

$res = $this->query($sql);

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_object($res)) {

  foreach ($uId as $key => $value) {

    $array[$key] .= ($row->NAME);

  }
}

  return $array;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not really clear what do you need, but I suppose it is:

```
$sql =
  " SELECT ".
  " D.U_ID AS ID, CONCAT(U_NAME,' ',U_SURNAME) AS NAME".
  " FROM TABLE1 AS D".
  " JOIN TABLE2 AS A".
  " ON D.U_ID = A.U_ID".
  " WHERE D.U_ID IN (".$Id.")".
  " GROUP BY U_ID";

$res = $this->query($sql);

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_object($res)) {
    $array[$row->ID] = $row->NAME;
}
```

Comment: In fact, on the previous page I select users. 
These users are associated with an ID.
I get the ID in question and I associate it with his name. (The one I get with the request)
The count in the array need to be my id and the value need to be the name.
The id are in post so you have to recover them with a foreach

Comment: __And the problem is__?

Comment: Because of my foreach in my while, the array looks like that

[id1] => Name1Name2

[id2] => Name1Name2

instead of

[id1] => Name1

[id2] => Name2

Comment: Yes but, "$row->ID" does not exist because, for have Id it's necessary than make a foreach "$uId as $key => $value" and $key = myId
Your code give me :
 [] => Name1

but i want to have :
[1] => Name1

[2] => Name2

Comment: `ID` is an alias in the sql query - __`D.U_ID AS ID`__. Have your read the answer fully?

Comment: Yes but, is not that ID but the ID which are in post value that needed.
In f12 menu -> network (Inspect script), in ajax.php I've user ids select before 
id[1]: on
id[2]: on
So, I need
$uId = gs_post('id');
foreach ($uId as $key => $value){...
But I can not make a array with those Id and the Name of the request

Comment: And how come that it's not that ID if you provide `WHERE ID IN (that ids)`?

Comment: With your code i'v got error
[error] Unable to perform query ( SELECT D.U_ID AS ID, CONCAT(U_NAME,' ',U_SURNAME) AS NAME FROM TABLE1 AS D JOIN TABLE2 AS A ON D.U_ID = A.U_ID WHERE D.U_ID IN (1,2) GROUP BY U_ID / Champ: 'U_ID' dans group statement est ambigu)